# 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs.WhereParameters' cannot be used like a method

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have used a gridview and linqdatasourse , the gridview will be fill by a linq-stored procedure after clicking a search button.

I did it like below but I have error  ""'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs.WhereParameters' cannot be used like a method"

```
var subjectFilter = e.WhereParameters("Subject");
```

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewDocuments_Search" 
              runat="server" 
              AutoGenerateColumns=False 
              Visible="False"
              onrowcommand="GridViewDocuments_Search_RowCommand"
              DataKeyNames="DocID" PageSize="100">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Details">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID ="btn_Show" 
                            Text="Details" 
                            runat= "server" 
                            CommandName= "Details" 
                            CommandArgument=
                                '<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentNo" 
                        HeaderText="DocumentNo" 
                        SortExpression="DocumentNo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="title" 
                        HeaderText="Title" 
                        SortExpression="title" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Docid" 
                        HeaderText="Docid" 
                        Visible="false" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource2" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ContextTypeName="EDMSDataContext" 
                    OnSelecting="LinqDataSource2_Selecting">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Subject"
                              ControlID="txtSearchKeywords"
                              PropertyName="Text"
                              Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Code:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
    this.LinqDataSource2.WhereParameters["Subject"].DefaultValue = 
                        this.txtSearchKeywords.Text;
    this.GridViewDocuments_Search.DataBind();
}


public void LinqDataSource2_Selecting(object sender, 
                                      LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();       
    var subjectFilter = e.WhereParameters("Subject");
    var query = _DataContext.spQuickSearchDoc(txtSearchKeywords.Text);
    e.Result = query;
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spQuickSearchDoc]
@Searchtext varchar(50)=null

AS

select DocId,DocumentNo,Title,Unit
from tblDocuments
where DocumentNo like '%'+@SearchText + '%'
    or Title like '%'+@SearchText + '%'
    or Unit like '%'+@SearchText + '%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method LinqDataSource2_Selecting you have to write "[" brackets like this:

```
var subjectFilter = e.WhereParameters["Subject"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the property `WhereParameters` can't be used like a method, like the exception says.
Query the property like:

```
e.WhereParameters["Subject"]
```

If you look into the `LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs` class you will see this property as:

```
public IDictionary<string, Object> WhereParameters { get; }
```

References:

[LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasourceselecteventargs.aspx)

[LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs.WhereParameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasourceselecteventargs.whereparameters.aspx)